# Division by 0.9 c# always returns 0

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to do a simple picee of maths where I work out if a value is between two values and if so, it does, it should do a simple division. However sometimes the value divided by are like 0.9, 0.6 etc and that always returns 0.

in this example,

```
int m_LocationSqrMtr = 4339;
float m_DefaultPricing = Convert.ToSingle(DefaultPricing);
float m_manDays;

if (m_LocationCosts > 450 && m_LocationCosts < 700)
{
    m_DefaultPricing = 700 / m_LocationSqrMtr;    
}
```

Comment: What is `m_LocationSqrMtr`?

Comment: integer division truncates after the decimal point. what type is m_LocationSqrMtr

Comment: @SLaks presumably its larger than `700`, in fact its `4339`

Comment: And he is not dividing by 0.9!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx

Comment: @abelenky, thats a zombie kitten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that the type of `m_LocationSqrMtr` is `int`, in which case this expression:

```
700 / m_LocationSqrMtr
```

... will be computed using *integer* arithmetic, and the result converted to `float`. I suspect you want:

```
if (m_LocationCosts > 450 && m_LocationCosts < 700)
{
    m_DefaultPricing = 700f / m_LocationSqrMtr;    
}
```

The `f` suffix on the literal means that it's a `float` literal, so first `m_LocationSqrMtr` will be promoted to `float`, and then the division performed using `float` arithmetic.

However, if this is meant to be representing *currency* values, you should consider using `decimal` instead of `float` - and then probably rounding the value to 2 decimal places. If you do all your currency arithmetic in `decimal`, you're less likely to run into unexpected results...

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. I've made m_DefaultPricing to be a decimal now, however it still returns 0. When it was a float putting the f did work (with a crazy amount of decimals). But what you've said is right. How do I get it working with a decimal?

Comment: @TomBeech: use the `m` suffix for decimal instead of `f`.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
int m_LocationSqrMtr = 4339;
[...]
m_DefaultPricing = 700 / m_LocationSqrMtr;
```

That is, `700 / 4339`, which is `(integer) / (integer)`, the result of which is an integer.

I know you were expecting an answer of `0.16132...`.

But in integer terms, that value is ***ZERO***.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of `m_LocationSqrMtr` is `int`, as in a 32-bit whole number, then the expression

```
700 / m_LocationSqrMtr
```

is one integer divided by another integer, and it's type is integer. Only after this integer is produced is the result assigned to the `float m_DefaultPricing`, so basically your code is equivalent to:

```
int temp = 700 / m_LocationSqrMtr;  
m_DefaultPricing = (float) temp;
```

If you want to force floating point arithmetic, at least one of the operands needs to be a floating point number. There are a number of ways that this can be done:

```
m_DefaultPricing = 700.0 / m_LocationSqrMtr; //explicit decimal point

m_DefaultPricing = 700f / m_LocationSqrMtr; //explicit float specification

m_DefaultPricing = (float)700 / m_LocationSqrMtr;  //casting one operand
m_DefaultPricing = 700f / (float)m_LocationSqrMtr; //into a float
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of good practical answers so on a more conceptual level:

In C# if both sides of the operator are an integer the result is also an integer and any decimal digits are truncated. In general, for math, the language will produce a result of the same type as the input with the most precise type. The type of variable you store the result in will have no effect on the result only the types of the inputs.

By forcing one input to be decimal or float you force the output to be that as well. In practice you can either do this by declaring your one of your input variables as a decimal or float (depending on which you use, in your case you would change the type of m_LocationSqrMtr) or if you have a constant input (as you do) you can force it to be decimal/float/double as follows:

```
var a = 10f // float
var b = 10d // double
var c = 10m // decimal
var d = 10.0 // double I believe
```